# Uses for extra science packs

Tags: factorio

I recently demolished my base because it had grown into a knotted mess (and I wanted an excuse to set up a roboport network).

I realized post-demolition that I have around 100k green and red science packs, and that I only need another 32k of each to finish all the remaining research (I still need ~20k of the blue and purples though).

Is there any use for my remaining ~70k red and green packs? Can I get materials back from them? Are they worth keeping for anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you intend to continue playing post 0.15 release, then you can just wait and use them for [Infinite Research](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-161), but beware of [Research Revolution](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-159).

Comment: Ohh, good find. Part 2 of my question (which I neglected to include for some reason) is "should I rebuild my red/green factories?". I take this as I should.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Note that the research costs are [planned to change as well](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-159). So you would probably have to rebuild the rest of your factory...

Comment: @Tim I ended up remaking the red and greens. Just in case.

Comment: 0.15 will disrupt all research anyway, not just cost  Really, I think only red and green will be the same (I think, but I might be wrong on green).  Kovarex posted about this in a recent FFF.  Which you should read if you don't.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard, which FFF exactly?

Comment: Here, let me google that for you ;-)  https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-159

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of mods, its not possible to recycle materials of any sort.  I found a [Steam forum post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/427520/discussions/0/412448158150520355/) discussing this matter.  You can destroy them by placing them in a chest and then destroying the chest, but that's not really a "use."

I also found a [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/27r5me/recyclingdisposal/) post that discusses the same topic.

There aren't any other uses for science packs besides using them for research.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257009/is-there-a-trashcan-function relevant question